# Code First Entity Framework connection string, Data Source keyword error

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Trying to get my first MVC + EF code first project to run.  The database does not yet exist.  this is my connection string, and my model is named FirstDB:

```
<add name="FirstDB" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=First; Integrated Security=SSPI; Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

The error I get says Data Source is not a recognized keyword.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

This is the guide I'm following, but unfortunately, they are using a sdf file, and all the other examples I've found are using a mdf file in user mode.  I don't want to do either of those.

If it is non-trivial to see, my question is: **How do I eliminate the error such that I can connect to the database server and have EF code first generate my database?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using wrong provider. Code first doesn't use `EntityClient`. That is provider only for EF with EDMX mapping file. Use `System.Data.SqlClient` directly. You also don't need to specify `Provider` inside the connection string itself.

Comment: I would have never figured that out.

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue and this fixed it.  Thanks!